# Retrieve data from database to my app (NOT WORKING)

Tags: java, android, json, database

so i am trying to retrieve data stored in my database.

basically the user inputs a car registration number and a rating (between 1-5)and click button. once the button is clicked my code will execute. which gets text from both editext and send to my server. i have php file saved, which will check if the carregistration number matches the value in the databse. if it matches retrieve the current rating stored in the database. the value is then showed on another acitivity.   The php file works fine. i tried by inserting value manually. the problem i have is that when the button is clicked nothign happens.  i have used this code to retrieve user name and other details on another app.

dataretrieve.java

```
public class DataRetrieve extends StringRequest {

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://dipteran-thin.000webhostapp.com/Login1.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public DataRetrieve (String carreg, int rating, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("carreg", carreg);
        params.put("rating", rating + "");



    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

Profile.java (where the user inputs carreg and rating)

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.carreg);
     final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String carreg = editText.getText().toString();
            final int rating = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString());

            // Response received from the server
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success) {

                            int rating = jsonResponse.getInt("rating");

                            Intent intent = new Intent(Profile.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("rating", rating);
                            Profile.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Profile.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            DataRetrieve loginRequest = new DataRetrieve(carreg, rating, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Profile.this);
            queue.add(loginRequest);
        }});
    }
}
```

userareaactivity.java (where value is shown when retrieved)

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);


    final TextView etusername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    final TextView etwelcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    final TextView etuname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    final Button Logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

    //String Name = SharedPreferenceUtils.getName(this);
    //etwelcome.setText(Name);




   Intent intent = getIntent();
   username = intent.getIntExtra("rating", -1);
    etusername.setText(username + "");








    //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Messages.class);
    //in.putExtra("username", username);
    //UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(in);

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){


}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserAreaActivity.this, Messages.class);
        UserAreaActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting an error from your php page:

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ']' in <b>/storage/ssd1/526/2972526/public_html/Login1.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
```

You can see the output of your response in the log by using this line above your JSON parsing (before it throws the exception)

```
Log.d("Response", response.toString());
```

I copied your success block into the exception block and it works as expected, so that code is valid. I would also put some kind of alert in the catch to let you know the failure happened when you're done testing.

Side note, change your parameter line to this...it's cleaner:

```
params.put("rating", String.valueOf(rating));
```

Comment: yea. i checked myphp file i had an extra bracket. so i fixed that up. i will try it now. thanks

Comment: Brother U ARE AWESOME. was able to fix it. thank you for spending time to help me out. have a nice day. :D

Comment: If your question has been answered don't forget to accept an answer and mark your thread as closed, best of luck with your app!

Comment: well i chose an answer. so di need to do anything else? how do i close the thread? i dont see any button